# Select query does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Query:

```
select * 
from etm 
where emp_id LIKE '009090%'
  AND directnumber LIKE '111 123 12345x 67%'
  AND cellnumber LIKE '123456789%'
  AND phone LIKE '111 123 12345x 67';
```

database: oracle 11g

Select query doesn't return any records when the LIKE operator has small X character (12345**x**) in it.

When I replace it with any other character (small/capital) it works ((12345**Y**)), but replacing it with the small x also does not work.

I cannot modify the query, is there anything can be done at database level while inserting the data? 
we are importing data in bulk.

Comment: Silly question, but does the data in the database contain the small 'x' character?  I don't see anything in Oracle documentation indicating the 'x' is treated specially in a LIKE clause, so I would assume there are simply no matching rows.

Comment: Replace the "x" with "_". Are u getting records with "x"  in the result set?

Comment: I understand its a silly question @Lotharyx, but why does the same query runs when I replace x with Y or X ?

Comment: @shank Yes it does work when I replace x with any other character like '-'.

Comment: @FlorinGhita following is the use case - step 1: I update a contact with '12345x' and try to search it using the LIKE operator mentioned in the query and I get no results. Then I update SAME record with '12345Y' and the select query returns the record.

Comment: @SumitNagrare I am asking if results have the value "x" in them...

Comment: Also can u post the record that u updated

Comment: shank asks for a good thing.  Please include the entire query (if any different from the one already in your question) and the data of the row that you think should be matching.  It seems very unlikely that Oracle would have a bug in handling the letter **x**...

Comment: And what happens if you update it back to `x` - does your query match then? Can you [`dump()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm) that value as it was before you updated it, or another one that has the same behaviour? I suspect what you are loading isn't actually a plain `x`, but just looks like it. ([Maybe one of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark), for example.) Or it is an `x` and what you are searching for isn't, which seems less likely.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an issue - here's a test case to demonstrate:

```
with sample_data as (select '123x 456' str from dual union all
                     select '123 456' str from dual union all
                     select '123x' str from dual union all
                     select 'abcx 93s' str from dual)
select *
from   sample_data
where  str like '123x%';

STR     
--------
123x 456
123x
```

So, you can see my search has pulled back rows where the str column starts with `123x`.

However, if I search for rows starting with `123y` then no rows are returned:

```
with sample_data as (select '123x 456' str from dual union all
                     select '123 456' str from dual union all
                     select '123x' str from dual union all
                     select 'abcx 93s' str from dual)
select *
from   sample_data
where  str like '123y%';

no rows selected.
```

since there are no rows where the str column starts with `123y`.

Is it a similar case with your data, where there aren't any rows that match all the filter conditions when you have an `x` in one or more of the `like` conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified this query but it should work.

```
select * 
from etm 
where emp_id LIKE '009090%'
  AND (directnumber LIKE '111%' or directnumber LIKE '123%' .....)
  AND cellnumber LIKE '123456789%'
  AND (phone LIKE '111' or phone LIKE '123' .......);
```

Reference : 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1096523?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: It won't give the right results though. It isn't looking for the `x`, and will match more values for the `directnumber` and `phone` columns, Why do you think the OP is trying to match multiple patterns in those columns?

Comment: Can you create sample environment on SQLFiddle?

Comment: It isn't my question; and SQL Fiddle has been broken for Oracle for some time now. But you don't seem to have addressed the actual issue.